# Why is my shader creating a bright point at the source origin?

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

I am trying to create a simple light shader but am getting results where the origin of the light is brighter then expected.

Note: The reason the shader code looks odd is because I believe SFML uses an older and non standard version of GLSL.

The shader

```
uniform vec2 size;
uniform vec2 origin;

void main() {


    float light_strength = 100.0;
    vec2 frag_location =  gl_FragCoord.xy;

    // Flip over the x axis
    frag_location.y = size.y - frag_location.y;

    // Get the distance from the fragment to the source
    float abs_distance = length(origin - frag_location);

    // Calculate the attenuation based on the distance
    // 1.0 / (1.0 + 1.0*d + 1.0*d^2)
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0 + (1.0 * abs_distance) + (1.0 * pow(abs_distance, 2.0))) * light_strength;

    // Create a base color
    vec4 light_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // Change the color based on the attenuation
    vec4 color = vec4(attenuation, attenuation, attenuation, 1.0) * light_color; 

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Example implementation

```
//libs: -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#define width 600
#define height 600

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Shader shader;
    sf::RenderStates states;

    window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "");

    // Create a shape to fill the screen
    sf::RectangleShape fill_color(sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
    fill_color.setSize(sf::Vector2f(width, height));
    fill_color.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

    // Shader gets compiled by whatever SFML uses for it
    shader.loadFromFile("shaders/lighting.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    // Set some origin point
    shader.setUniform("size", sf::Vector2f(width, height));
    shader.setUniform("origin", sf::Vector2f(300, 300));
    states = &shader;


    while (window.isOpen()) {

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)) {
            window.close();
        }

        // Draws
        window.clear();
        window.draw(fill_color, states);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

[Result of implementation code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LiH4.png)

Comment: `abs_distance=0` -> `attenuation=100*1/(1+0+0)=100`;  `abs_distance=1` -> `attenuation=100*1/(1+1+1)=33`;  `abs_distance=5` -> `attenuation=100*1/(1+5+25)=3.23`. All will be clamped to 1.0.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the expected output is between 0 and 1. But what I am seeing suggests that the somewhere, whether in the shader code or the drawing itself, the colour value of the pixel is 255. I appreciate the feedback, but all you did was give me the output of my own equation.

Comment: All values >=1.0 in GLSL color output corresponds to 255 in unsigned byte color buffer (`GL_RGBA8`, which is a "normalized" format). So I'm really misunderstand current question...